# '\n' and '\r' recognized as 2 characters instead of 1

Tags: c

I got a null terminated buffer (filled using 'read' syscall) with the following content:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: 127.0.0.1\r\n\r\n
```

I'm trying to replace `\r` and `\n` characters by `*` characters, but when I loop the buffer the characters aren't modified.

```
for (long i = 0; i < bytes_read; i++) {
  if (buffer[i] == '\r' || buffer[i] == '\n')
      buffer[i] = '*';
}
```

Where 'bytes_read' is the amount of bytes returned by 'read' syscall.

But there buffer isn't modified, and if I print it character by character, '\r' and '\n' are print as '' and 'r'.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Does the string actually have the backslash character followed by `n` by `r`, rather than the single characters represented by `\n` or `\r`?

Comment: @FredLarson Wouldn't that be two characters? `buffer[i]` is a single character

Comment: @ArdentCoder: Yes, that's what I mean. That could be a reason they're not being replaced.

Comment: What if you `printf` the string as it is? How does it look like? Also make sure `bytes_read` is correct.

Comment: Escape sequences aren't processed in data, they're only processed in string and character literals in source code. So if you have `\n` in the buffer, it's 2 characters, not translated to newline.

Comment: Try printing the numeric value of each element of `buffer`. If you see a value of 92 decimal (0x5c hexadecimal), that's a backslash character. `printf("%d\n", buffer[i]);`

Answer (score 2):

If `read` is returning `5C 6E`, it's because the stream contains the ASCII encoding of a backslash (`\`) and `n`. If the stream contained the ASCII encoding of a line feed, `read` would return `0A`.